# Why does console give errors after fetching data from API Angular

Tags: angular, http

I'm fetching data from API and want to display tabs for each object value.
Everything works fine, just getting error in the console. `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Projects')`
Data is displaying correctly as it should. I'm assuming it cannot read it at first so it says it's undefined. And after fetching data appears.

How should I get rid of this error?

HTML:

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let object of projects.Projects; let i = index" label="{{ object.Id }}"></mat-tab>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TablesService } from "../tables/tables.service";

@Component({...})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  projects: any;
  constructor(public tableService: TablesService)
  {
    this.tableService.fetchAPI().subscribe((data) => {
      this.projects = data;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `projects` is only declared and not initialized, so until your API call is completed and you put some data in that variable, it will be `undefined`. One way to deal with this is to assume that `projects` could be `undefined` and use the `?` (optional chaining operator) to account for that:

```html
<mat-tab *ngFor="let object of projects?.Projects; let i = index" label="{{ object.Id }}"></mat-tab>
```

Another solution could be to give an initial value to the `projects` property:

```
projects: any = {};
```

Comment: ok, that's what I thought at first but didn't know it would be that simple! It works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The template will be rendered before the server has responded

So here, `projects` will be temporarily `undefined`

```html
<mat-tab *ngFor="let object of projects.Projects; let i = index" label="{{ object.Id }}"></mat-tab>
```

You can use an `*ngIf` to prevent this part being rendered until `projects` is defined. But, as you can put only one structural operator, you will have to add a `ng-container` around it :

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="projects">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let object of projects.Projects; let i = index" label="{{ object.Id }}"></mat-tab>
</ng-container>
```

Or you can also add a `?` after `projects`, like this :

```html
<mat-tab *ngFor="let object of projects?.Projects; let i = index" label="{{ object.Id }}"></mat-tab>
```